# C++17/20 - array-like initialization for fixed size container class

Tags: c++, templates, containers, c++20, list-initialization

I have a specialized, templated container class containing a fixed size array (size defined by a template):

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class container {

protected:
T _arr[N];
std::size_t _size = 0;      // does not necessarily equal N
\* other members *\

public:
\* ctors and member functions *\
};
```

Now I would like to initialize its underlying array like a c-array:

```
container c = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

This line of code should initialize `_arr` as an integer array containing `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }`.

Meanwhile I want to be able to use other constructors as well. For example:

```
container c(size, value);     // initializes _arr until size with value
```

My idea of an ideal implementation would be a way to pass the size of a (constexpr) initializer list to the template argument size.

### *What I tried:*

#### 1. Using a constructor with an array as parameter:

```
container(const T (&arr)[N]) : _size(N) {
    std::copy(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), _arr);
}
```

This works, when using it directly in the constructor: `container c({ 1, 2, 3, 4})`, but does not work when using copy construction: `container c = {1, 2, 3, 4}`. Using another set of curly braces around the array would fix the problem (`container c = {{1, 2, 3, 4}}`), but this is not what I was thinking when I first envisioned this class.

#### 2. Using a constructor with variadic templates

```
template<typename ...U, typename = std::enable_if<std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T, U>...>> >
container(U... values) : _size(sizeof...(U)) {
    T a[] = {values...};
    std::move(std::begin(a), std::end(a), _arr);
}
```

and a type deduction guide:

```
template<typename ...T>
container(T...) -> container<std::common_type_t<T...>, sizeof...(T)>;
```

This was the closest I got, but it unfortunately messud up the use of constructors directly (`container c(size, value)`).

---

My idea of an ideal implementation would be a way to pass the size of the initializer list as a template argument (using a type deduction guide for example):

```
container(std::initializer_list<T> list) : _size(list.size()) {
    std::copy(std::begin(list), std::end(list), _arr);
}
```

```
template<typename L, 
         typename T = L::value_type, 
         typename = std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<L, std::initializer_list<T>>> >
container(L init_list) -> container<T, init_list.size()>;
```

This obviously does not compile (`error: template argument 2 is invalid`).

Is there a way realize this, preferably in a constexpr way?

Comment: (1) looks like the best solution.

Comment: I'd be tempted to study std::array for inspiration, as it is so similar.

Comment: `\\* other members *\\` - what is that invalid C++?

Answer (score 2):

What you have is similar to [`inplace_vector`](https://wg21.link/p0843r9) / [`static_vector`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html). These have had a lot of thought put in to them and chose to *not* support CTAD precisely because the maximum capacity isn't readily deducible.

However, if your use case is that the initial size is usually the maximum size, you can do it with a mix of option 2 and 3. You can't get the size of an `initializer_list` argument at compile time, but a deduction guide doesn't have to correspond to a constructor. You can do something like this:

```cpp
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class container {
    // ...
    // initializer_list constructor, like in (3)
    container(std::initializer_list<T> list) : _size(list.size()) {
        std::copy(std::begin(list), std::end(list), _arr);
    }
};

// Parameter pack deduction guide, like in (2)
template<typename... T>
container(T...) -> container<std::common_type_t<T...>, sizeof...(T)>;

container c{1, 2, 3};
// container<int, 3> deduced from deduction guide, initializer_list<int> constructor used
```

Comment: I did indeed stumble upon both of them, and became curious whether it was possible, thank you, it works for me